# Trying to pull top product by customer group

Tags: magento-1.7

Does Magento have the ability to provide top selling products by customer group ID? I have dug through the default reports and nothing has caught my eye.

I'm not trying my hand at raw SQL queries to no avail.

My solution:

```
SELECT  items.order_id AS orderid,
    items.item_id AS itemid,
    orders.total_item_count AS total_items_in_order,
    items.product_type,
    items.sku AS itemcode,
    items.created_at AS orderdate,
    base_total_paid,
    count(items.sku) as totalOccurence,
    items.name AS itemname
FROM mg_sales_flat_order AS orders 
    JOIN mg_sales_flat_order_item AS items 
      ON items.order_id = orders.entity_id 
    LEFT JOIN mg_sales_flat_order_address AS address
      ON orders.entity_id = address.parent_id
WHERE ((customer_group_id=7) OR (base_total_paid>=200)) and
     items .created_at > date_sub(now(), interval 4 year)  
GROUP BY items.sku 
ORDER BY count(items.sku) DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: customer group ID or customer ID?

Comment: Sorry, Customer Group ID. See my post for what I was able to put together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik there is neither a report to get the top selling product by customer group nor by customer id.

But you can easily get it from the database:

```
SELECT item.sku, COUNT(*) as count, order.customer_id 
  FROM sales_flat_order_item item 
  INNER JOIN sales_flat_order order 
    ON order.entity_id = item.order_id 
  GROUP BY customer_id
  ORDER BY count DESC
```